# what does tilde mean?

Tags: operator-keyword, tilde

a ~= b*c;
It can't be boolean logic, so what's that?

Comment: Mind telling us what language?

Comment: In what language? A binary `bitwise NOT` operator doesn't make sense, and `~` is usually `bitwise NOT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` gives the bitwise complement of a single integer....

So it could be that here b and c multiply and then bits of the number get reversed.